# Remove Address Bar of Webpage Accessed Through TWA

Tags: android, reactjs, trusted-web-activity

I'm currently working on a TWA and I need to redirect the user to another web app I created.  The problem is when the user redirects to the other web app, the page now has a address bar.  My goal is to confine the user within the app, but with the address bar present it's possible for users to open a chrome instance and break out of the app.  That being said, is it possible to keep address bar removed when redirecting out of the TWA?